# How do I access my legacy games using the Battle.net desktop app?

Tags: diablo-ii, battle.net, starcraft, warcraft-3

The Battle.net desktop PC app seems to only have *World of Warcraft*, *Starcraft 2*, *Diablo 3* and *Hearthstone* available for launch and updates. But I also have purchased and attached *Diablo 2* and *D2: Lord of Destruction* CD keys to my Battle.net account, but they're not listed.

Among other legacy games are *Warcraft 3: Reign of Chaos*, *WC3: Frozen Throne*, *Starcraft* and *SC: Brood War* expansion.

Is there some way I can access these legacy games using the app?

Comment: btw, Blizzard classics *Blackthorne*, *The Lost Vikings* and *Rock'n'Roll Racing* are [available for free on Battle.net](https://us.battle.net/account/download/) since May 2014

Comment: You forgot the best game Warcraft 2 BNE (Battle.net Edition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't, unfortunately.

The Battle.net desktop application does not have any support for what Blizzard refer to as "legacy games". This means that Diablo 2 and the Lord of Destruction expansion (amongst many others) are not available for installation or management through the Battle.net desktop application and can only be installed by logging into Battle.net and downloading the installers.

> "All of the classic games will come to the app eventually. We'd love to do it now. It really boils down to having time and resources." -Vexis
>
> Source: http://us.battle.net/en/forum/topic/13349474866#4

Comment: Can you launch them VIA the app after installation has already been done?

Comment: No, the app only provides support for Diablo 3, Starcraft 2, and World of Warcraft. Everything else is considered a legacy game and is not supported in the app.

Comment: That sucks. Was hoping for a kind of a Steam vibe.. Maybe they will still add it. Don't care much for the support, just want to have all my Blizzard games in on place though. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: As a side-note, if you use Steam then you can [add non-Steam game shortcuts to your Steam library](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2219-YDJV-5557)